# Limits of cosine and sine

Tags: limits, trigonometry

When $\theta$ is very small why $\sin \theta$ is similar to $\theta$ and $\cos\theta$ similar to $1$? Is it related to limits or we can prove it simply by using diagrams?

Comment: maybe you would like to prove $\lim_{x\to0}(\sin x - x) =0$ :-)

Comment: @Math-fun How would that help? One might also prove $\lim_{x\to 0}(\sin x - x^2) = 0$ alas that does not imply $\sin x \approx x^2$,,,,

Comment: @CiaPan ups you are right, thanks! one could look at the ratio $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ then turn to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1

Comment: Yes, you can visualize it using a diagram. I have uploaded a diagram and explanation. However, this can't be called a 'proof', because a proof needs to be rigorous.

Comment: @CiaPan: Yes it does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the unit circle, $\theta$ is the length of the arc (as well as the angle extended by that arc). (Thus, perimeter of the unit circle is $2\pi$). Whereas, $\cos\theta$ is the length of the $X$ intercept, and $\sin\theta$ is the length of the $Y$ intercept.

Look at the following diagram:
[image]

You can now easily visualize that when Point P approaches closer to $(1,0)$, then $\theta \rightarrow \ 0$. At this time, the arc in question will become almost a vertical line, and the $Y$ intercept of the arc is almost the same length as the arc.

Hence as $\theta \rightarrow \ 0$ then $\sin\theta \rightarrow \theta$

And, at that time, the length of the $X$ intercept will get closer and closer to $1$.

Hence as $\theta \rightarrow \ 0$ then $\cos\theta \rightarrow 1$

Also, from this figure, you can easily visualize that when Point P approaches $(0,1)$, the $Y$ intercept will approach $1$ and the $X$ intercept will have same length as the length of the remaining part of the arc (from point P to point $(0,1)$)
which is $(\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta)$. (Remember that total length of the arc from $(1,0)$ to $(0,1)$ is $\frac{\pi}{2}$).

Thus, we have:

$\theta \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}$ then $\sin\theta \rightarrow 1$, and

$\theta \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}$ then $\cos\theta \rightarrow (\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta)$

Comment: Why do you consider the length of arc to be $\theta$?

Comment: I am not _considering_ the length of the arc to be $\theta$, actually it is *a fact*. The length of the arc of the unit circle IS taken as the angle extended by that arc, this is called Radian angle. Please refer to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian. Thus, $90\textdegree$=$\frac{\pi}{2}$, and $180\degree$=$\pi$, and $270\degree$=$\frac{3\pi}{2}$, and $360\degree$=$2\pi$, and so on...

Comment: Let me guess, is an unit circle is a circle of radius 1 unit?

Comment: Yes, dear friend! A unit circle is a circle of radius 1, that's why we call it *Unit Circle*.  That's why it intersects $X$ axis at $(1,0)$, and $(-1,0)$, and it intersects $Y$ axis at $(0,1)$, and $(0,-1)$.

Comment: Oh thanks, I got it..

Comment: @voyager Apparently there is no \degree or \textdegree command in the TeX implementation on MSE. You migh use superscript circle instead — **2^\circ** renders as $2^\circ$

Comment: @CiaPan,, yes I was searching on various websites and trying to get the desired output. But after I experimented with a few suggestions, time ran out and my comment was blocked for further editing... You know StackExchange allows editing a comment within 5 minutes only.

Comment: @voyager When in doubt, I usually experiment with a draft answer, which has an instant preview and no time limit, and cut-and-paste to a comment space when done. :)  [EOT](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/EOT)?

Comment: @CiaPan, thanks a lot for this helpful tip. I am a new user, and getting my head around... EOT! :-)

Answer (score 13):

Using the [Taylor series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series), we can express $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ as

$$\displaystyle\sin(x) = x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} - \dots$$

$$\displaystyle\cos(x) = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} - \dots$$

Note that when $x \ll 1$, then $x^2 \ll x$ and $x^3 \ll x^2$ and so on. Any higher powers of $x$ will be *very small*. Then the above functions can be approximated by their first terms.

$$\displaystyle\sin(x) \approx x $$

$$\displaystyle\cos(x) \approx 1 $$

Comment: I get it sir. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you use circular function approach to define $\cos \theta$ then for very small but positive $\theta$, we have $\cos \theta = x$ where $x$ is the $x$ coordinate of the point on the unit circle which lies on the terminal side of the angle $\theta$. From the unit circle, you can see that as $\theta$ gets smaller and smaller, $x$ gets bigger and bigger and tends toward the point $(1,0)$ on the $x$ axis. This works like a proof of your claim.

Answer (score 0):

See Wikipedia [Small-angle approximation — Geometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-angle_approximation#Geometric):

in a right triangle the side opposite to the small angle is *almost* same length as the corresponding circular arc, which in turn is equal to the angle (see the definition of [radian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian)), hence sine approximately equal the angle. At the same time the long leg is *almost* equal to hypotenuse, making the cosine approximately equal $1$.